# Check if a file is 20 hours old in ansible

Tags: file, datetime, time, ansible, stat

I'm able to get the timestamp of a file using Ansible `stat` module.

```yaml
- stat:
    path: "/var/test.log"
  register: filedets

- debug:
    msg: "{{ filedets.stat.mtime }}"
```

The above prints mtime as `1594477594.631616` which is difficult to understand.

I wish to know how can I put a `when` condition check to see if the file is less than 20 hours old?

Answer (score 9):

You can also achieve this kind of tasks without going in the burden to do any computation via [`find`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html) and its [`age`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html#parameter-age) parameter:

In your case, you will need a negative value for the `age`:

> Select files whose age is equal to or greater than the specified time.
> Use a negative age to find files equal to or less than the specified time.
> You can choose seconds, minutes, hours, days, or weeks by specifying the first letter of any of those words (e.g., "1w").

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html#parameter-age*</sup>

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  
  tasks:
    - file:
        path: /var/test.log
        state: touch

    - find:
        paths: /var
        pattern: 'test.log'
        age: -20h
      register: test_log

    - debug:
        msg: "The file is exactly 20 hours old or less"
      when: test_log.files | length > 0 

    - file:
       path: /var/test.log
       state: touch
       modification_time: '202007102230.00'

    - find:
        paths: /var
        pattern: 'test.log'
        age: -20h
      register: test_log

    - debug:
        msg: "The file is exactly 20 hours old or less"
      when: test_log.files | length > 0
```

This gives the recap:

```
PLAY [all] **********************************************************************************************************

TASK [file] *********************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [find] *********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "The file is exactly 20 hours old or less"
}

TASK [file] *********************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [find] *********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=5    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 7):

```
- stat:
    path: "/var/test.log"
  register: filedets

- debug:
    msg: "{{ (ansible_date_time.epoch|float - filedets.stat.mtime ) > (20 * 3600) }}"
```